# why docker machine always open in super user mode?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, superuser

I am learning docker currently.

one thing that I noticed is that whenever I create a new machine using command :

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

& after running this command, if I start my docker-machine using:

```
docker start default
```

it will always prompt me with super user mode. i.e I always see # instead of $ in my terminal.

I would like like to know why this is happening?

is there particular requirement?

if possible, can I use normal user mode in this terminal?

any inputs?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's the thing with **docker**: "security isn't the primary requirement".

So, the not-so nice reality is: by default, when docker is doing something, it happens with root permissions. You actually have to put in "work" in order to not use privileged containers; and to run process **not** as root.

In essence: one should a good amount of research to understand the risks and solutions around "security of containers"; see [here](http://container-solutions.com/docker-security-cheat-sheet/) for example.